getting Steam to work with my nVidia Card on Ubuntu
I am looking for a little friendly guidance on how to get my nVidia GTX 1050ti Graphics Card to be properly recognised by the Linux version of Steam.
I am using the Ubuntu 20.04.06 distro of Linux and I will try to keep my question short and to the point here.
The default install of Ubuntu was using the standard built-in xorg driver. I successfully changed this to the Proprietary nVidia driver and I find that version 535 works best with my system. This was also recommended by Linux when searching for the correct driver.
I used the ppa-drivers repository for the correct nVidia driver as I am led to understand that the official nVidia driver does not include the 32-bit drivers in their package. The ppa repository purports to use both 32 bit and 64 bit in one package. I needed both sets of drivers before I could get Steam to actually launch because it flatly refused to launch when using 64-bit only drivers.
Having successfully installed the correct drivers and successfully got my card recognised by Ubuntu I am now at a stage where Steam will not see the primary vram and, in some cases, refuses to recognise DirectX compatibility either. My Steam System Info reports the following:
Driver: Mesa/X.org llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)
Driver Version: 3.1 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL Version: 4.5
Desktop Color Depth: 24 bits per pixel
Monitor Refresh Rate: 60 Hz
VendorID: 0x10de
DeviceID: 0x1c82
Revision Not Detected
Number of Monitors: 2
Number of Logical Video Cards: 1
Primary Display Resolution: 1920 x 1080
Desktop Resolution: 3840 x 1080
Primary Display Size: 18.78" x 10.55" (21.54" diag), 47.7cm x 26.8cm (54.7cm diag)
Primary Bus: PCI Express 16x
**Primary VRAM Not Detected**
Supported MSAA Modes: 2x 4x 8x 16x

This is causing issues with certain games that require 3D acceleration such as Assassins Creed 2, which also reports that the card or the driver do not support Direct X 9c despite me having installed DirectX compatibility using both Winetricks and Protontricks.
Other games actually do recognise DirectX such as Deus Ex Revision, Cat Quest and House Flipper which play flawlessly (using Proton on Steam) when using the current graphics driver.
I am stuck at this point and would really appreciate any advice on what I should do next to resolve my issue with Steam and my graphics card as I am unable to play a lot of Proton-enabled games due to the fact that the game screen either does not launch (the game launches and runs in the background, just no game screen) or it just closes out to the desktop with no error message.
The games I am trying to run are listed as Gold on ProtonDB and I do understand that tweaking is needed... I just don't know enough about what to tweak outside of what I have already tried;) I feel that this is a graphics driver issue but maybe some of you could correct me if I am wrong here.
Apologies for the long post but I wanted to give as much info as I could in the initial post. I will be more than happy to post any further info as required. Thanks in advance ;)

As the issue is Steam specific have you looked at asking Steam Support.

Interesting, I used 20.04 and have the same video card and didn't have any issues. Unfortunately that system is now converted to Debian 12 (also uses the 1050ti successfully with Steam) so I can't give directly comparable info.  I didn't use any ppa-drivers repo but only the official drivers from the Ubuntu repos.

Steam is definitely not seeing your nvidia driver so I wonder if it's actually installed. The report on this system looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/ynkcWD8.png Without specific knowledge of what's going on, I suggest purging any nvidia stuff you have from a ppa and installing the driver from the Ubuntu repos. That always worked for me. I also didn't do anything with winetricks or protontricks, I wonder if that muddied the waters.

What does your nvidia-settings screen look like?

Thank you for your replies. @david-de I will certainly look into using that forum if that is where I should be posting this, thanks for the suggestion.

Thank you for your reply Organic Marble, just taking you up on a couple of your comments, I did at one point use the purge steam command to remove it completely as well as deleting the hidden .steam folder as well to ensure complete deletion. I re-installed using the Software Manager however I used the Steam Installer that linked to the steampowered.com link and not the canonical steam-snap repository. I don't know if that would make a difference except that the steampowered repository was more up-to-date.

My nvidia-settings screen reports the following:
inLine 'Operating System Linux-x86_64
NVIDIA Driver Version 535.183.01
Server Version Number 11.0
Server Version String The X.Org Foundation
Server Vendor Version 1.20.13 (12013000)
NV-Control Version 1.29
Screens 1'
I find the Screens 1 very curious as I actually have 2 screens.
I agree that it is possible that winetricks or protontricks may have muddied the waters but I did try installing and running without using these options to start with.

Here is a link to a snapshot of my nVidia Settings as reported by nvidia-settings:
[link]https://freeimage.host/i/dSFqsne

Apologies for the bad code formatting I just cannot get the ''' barring to work in the comments box :(

OK, looks like your driver is definitely installed. I also used the steam from steampowered.com. I am not smart enough about Steam to know why it is ignoring your driver.

Thanks for trying Organic Marble, your input is appreciated. It does confirm that I am looking in the right area to try and solve this. I may try to find a 'relevant' area to post over on Steam Support as suggested by David earlier in this thread. If anybody else can offer any insight into this problem then please post your thoughts, all constructive replies would be very much appreciated at this stage ;)

A right click on a desktop icon for a steam game should offer "Launch with dedicated graphics card" -- does it and does it work?

Thank you for the reply @ubfan1, I appreciate your input. In response to your suggestion I have been copying shortcuts to the desktop, and test-installing games with desktop shortcuts. My current distro and Steam Install does not give me an option to "Launch with dedicated Graphics Card" however it does allow me to "open" the game after I check the box which is labelled "allow launching". This pops up a box asking me to launch Steam however if I do not choose that option and do nothing, the game will automatically launch and run...

I have tried this with Deus Ex Human Revolution and the game does now launch however I confess that I have also been experimenting with the driver installation just before your post and I used the command sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-535:i386

This appears to have solved a few game-launcher problems however it does not solve the original issue of Steam not recognising my graphics card or drivers. Steam firmly reports that there is no accelerated graphics card or DirectX compatible driver available so while your suggestion works, I am still unsure as the the reason that Steam does not enumerate my hardware properly. However I do thank you for this suggestion, it is another positive step forward into solving this issue and I am grateful for your help, thank you ;)
